# How can I update Firebase field value using Rest API

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database, crud

The result of Firebase RestAPI - https://profile-feab8-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/user0.json - is as below.

```
{
  "contact":{
    "email":"topsan72@gmail.com",
    "phone":"770-777-0073"
  },
  "name":{
    "firstname":"Donggeun",
    "nickname":"Dennis",
    "secondname":"Jung"
  }
}
```

I wanna know the RestAPI which updates the value of "phone" key to "777-777-7777".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to issue a PATCH request. As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-update): "Using a PATCH request, we can update specific children at a location without overwriting existing data".

Concretely you need to issue the following HTTP request:

```
curl -X PATCH -d '{
  "phone": "777-777-7777"
}' \
  'https://profile-feab8-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/user0/contact.json'
```

Comment: I tried your tip and failed by using - https://resttesttest.com/

I tried both 'Put' & 'Post' for 'Method'.
Set 'https://profile-feab8-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/user0/contact.json' for 'Endpoint'.
Set 'phone' for 'Parameter Name' and '777-777-7777' for 'Parameter Value'

Do you know what I missed?

Comment: The data to be written has to be passed as the **body** of the request, not as URL parameters.